# How to add png file as logo to gazebo model's .STL file and the model desciption is .sdf.jinja format?

Tags: stl, ros, sdf

I have been trying to add image file to a mesh type stl file by using

```
<script>
           <name>Logo/R2S</name> 
           <uri>model://r2s_cupcar/materials/scripts/logo.material</uri>
           <uri>model://r2s_cupcar/materials/logo/r2s.png</uri>
</script>
```

Changes I have made in .material file:

```
material Logo/R2S
{
    technique
    {
        pass
        {
            texture_unit
            {
                texture r2s.png
                scale 150.0  1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model>
  <name>R2S Cup Car</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <sdf version="1.5">r2s_cupcar.sdf</sdf>
  <author>
    <name>Benjamin Perseghetti</name>
    <email>bperseghetti@rudislabs.com</email>
  </author>
  <description>A model of the R2S Cup Car.</description>
</model>
```

I have also tried adding the png image to the gazebo model which was successfully added to the geometry in blender but is not importing in gazebo as it is i.e. no changes are visible in gazebo model.

Everywhere leads are available for collada(.dae) but Its mendatory to use .STL files in our model.So, Please guide me about its further process on further changes I can make in my .sdf.jinja file to include logo image properly as for now I am just getting different colours from my image file on the model. Thanks in advance.